# What is RouteBuilders in apache camel and what is it used for?

Tags: apache-camel

I want to know what is Route-builders in Apache camel? And why is it used for?
I have a project where JMS and apache camel are used but i dont know what is routebuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In advance: I am not 100% sure about the long answer, so please correct me if I am fundamentally wrong here!

**Short**:
The basic [definition](https://camel.apache.org/routebuilder.html) given by the official apache camel docu states:

> The RouteBuilder is a base class which is derived from to create
>   routing rules using the DSL. Instances of RouteBuilder are then added
>   to the CamelContext.

**Long**:
[Routebuilder](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/builder/RouteBuilder.html) is an abstract class. When implementing your own route, you usually extend from that RouteBuilder class (as the citation above already stated). 
As a consequence you must implement the method `configure()` in which you implement the route (`from()`/`.to()`/`.process()` etc.)

I am pretty sure it is possible to implement a route without extending RouteBuilder, but then you would have to rebuild the framework given by apache camel. The whole syntax (`from()`/`.to()`/`.process()` etc.) for implementing routes is provided by extending Routebuilder class.

Apache Camel is a framework. In order to use the framework your "route class" must inherit from the base classes of the given framework. Otherwise you would not be able use the framework, which already offers a huge part of the implementation.

If [Claus Ibsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406429/claus-ibsen) answers your question, stick to his answer, he knows virtually everything about apache camel.

Comment: Great answer metters. If you have a copy of my book CiA2 then you can read chapter 2, section 2.3 that goes more in depth what RouteBuilder is. But as metters say, its essentially a base class you extend where you then configure/design your Camel routes, that defines how messages are routed between endpoints and where you can use EIP patterns in these routes.

Comment: And yeah you can avoid the RouteBuilder class but it has the fluent builder syntax that makes it easier to define Camel routes. But you can build the routes manually with regular Java code and use constructors, getter/setters to build up the model of your routes from the model classes. But no Camel end users should really do that. Some frameworks that build their own Camel routes via some logic etc can do this.

Comment: On top of what others said already, RouteBuilders can be used for separation of concerns in a business application. We run few applications that has Camel at their core. They have ~50 routes. They help us to keep house keeping routes, reconciliation routes and routes around each business processes separate. They are all finally assembled and hooked into a single camel context.